# How to design a table to save daily data that may be new or same as previous day into MySQL efficiently?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a script to check some product sale prices on a website daily and would like to store it in a MySQL database.

There is a product table that stores productID, name, attributes etc. I thought of two ways to construct the sale price table.

1. productID, SalePrice, SalePriceDate. This will be store a record per product every day if there is a sale price. It is likely to end up saving the same record repeated for many days.
2. productID, SalePrice, FromDate, ToDate. When a sale price of a product is first found, it inserts a record with productID, SalePrice, FromDate, null ToDate. If there is no change on the days afterwards, do nothing. When a new sale price of the same product is detected one day, it updates ToDate to today()-1.

Which way is better? I suppose the first way saves a lot of duplicate data every day. The second way, how can I compare the source data vs what is the in sale price table and insert only new, update the existing ToDate and ignore the rest? Does it take more resource to process data like this? Do FromDate and ToDate make future query difficult to construct or slower to execute? The types of queries I am considering will be finding the the first start date of sale price given a date range, finding the total number of days a product is on sale given a date range, finding when a product is on sale or not on sale giving a date range for example. I am quite new to MySQL so have not checked on the advanced queries.

Thanks!

Comment: Better for what?  Both ways of storing the data are quite reasonable.  Which is better depends on how the data will be used -- and other factors as well (how often do prices change for instance).  As phrased, the question has too many questions and is inviting opinion.

Comment: See `INSERT IGNORE` and `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with the second approach because it seems to make sense more with regards to saving memory and your use cases.
Now for each of your questions:

Q: How can I compare the source data vs what is the in sale price table and insert only new, update the existing ToDate and ignore the rest?

A: You compare the SalePrice the same productID between the sale price table and your source data where you get the latest record for the productID from the sale price table (where ToDate is null). Another way of looking at it is you only query the products from the source data that have a different SalePrice value than the value in sale price table OR the product hasn't been inserted into the sale price table but is in the new source data (new product, comes with daily data).

Q:  Does it take more resource to process data like this?
A: I would yes, but this does not mean that you'll be spending a lot of computing power, this is just some logic instead of the old `insert into table select * from another_table`. You will be saving memory, so tradeoffs have to occur. When you would analyze your table with SQL you wouldn't have to go aggregations (like you would using approach 1), so this saves a bit of computing power.

Q: Do FromDate and ToDate make future query difficult to construct or slower to execute?
A: Let's say you want to get the price for a product on a certain date -> WHERE productId = your_productID and your_desired_date between DateFrom and DateTo
Let's say you want to get how the sale price has changed over time for some product -> WHERE productId = your_productID and so on...So depending on your SQL skills I think this shouldn't be that difficult. With approach 1 you'll have to do aggregations, with approach 2 you'll have to use temporal logic a bit more.

Q: The types of queries I am considering will be finding the the first start date of sale price given a date range, finding the total number of days a product is on sale given a date range, finding when a product is on sale or not on sale giving a date range for example.

A: I think that your queries will be even more performant if you go with design approach 2 if your use case is to find the first start date of a sale price (with the first approach you'll have to use aggregate function, MIN()). Also your query will be even more performant if you go with approach 2 if you want to get total number of days because you colud use DATEDIFF(DateFrom, DateTo), this is psevdo code please see documentation for MySQL for a function that finds date difference between to dates in days. If you want to see if a product is on sale or not within a date range approach 2 would be more cumbersome than approach 1, but not a lot. You'll just have to see if you have a record in your table for that product for the date range, if you don't then the product wasn't on sale, otherwise it was on sale.

**Conclusion: I would go with approach 2.**